# C# : convert files of a forlder to base64string

Tags: c#, file, directory

i want to convert all the files of a folder to base64string, but i have an error of System.UnauthorizedAccessException
i checked the security of the folder i have permission RWE
do you have a solution or other recommendations to do this need

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string FileLocation = @"C:\Users\mmm\Desktop\Nouveaudossier 2";
            string destinationPath = @"c:\folder";
            string[] fileEntries = Directory.GetFiles(FileLocation);
            foreach (string fileName in fileEntries)
            {
                Byte[] bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(fileName);
                String file = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);

                Byte[] bytess = Convert.FromBase64String(file);
                File.WriteAllBytes(destinationPath, bytess);
            }
            Console.WriteLine("done...........");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
```

Comment: Have you also checked each file?

Comment: What OS are you using ? One isn't allowed to create files under ``C:\`` without elevated rights (you might need to execute your program as administrator)

Comment: **Never** use hardcoded paths ! If you want to access your own desktop folder, use [`Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.DesktopDirectory))`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.environment.specialfolder?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: You do not have permission to write to the c:\ folder (the root) on your machine.

Comment: stickybit : it's a big number of files
cid : i use windows 10

Comment: I didn't ask about the number of files. Besides, when you run the program in the debugger you can check which files causes the error if any.

Comment: jdweng i change to another directory i have always the same error

Comment: sticky bit sorry this is the error ____ An unhandled exception of type 'System.UnauthorizedAccessException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
L'accès au chemin d'accès 'c:\folder' est refusé.

Comment: File.WriteAllBytes(destinationPath, bytess); looks like it is trying to write to a directory  without a filename specified i.e. File.WriteAllBytes(destinationPath + "\" + filename, bytess) might solve your issue.

Answer (score 1):

majita is right you are missing file name at your destinationPath,because File.WriteAllBytes expects file not directory. It should work that way